# NSString not showing in UILabel

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring, uilabel

My NSString does not show in my UILabel.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    NSString *schoolString = user[KEY_SCHOOL];
    NSLog(@"%@", schoolString);
    school.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", schoolString];

}
```

NSLog does return a valid result. My label is connected properly in IB and everything as well.

Very odd bug.

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like a UILabel in  your code snippet up there.  Where are you setting your UILabel?

Comment: Did you NSLog school as well?

Comment: `school` object seems to be a `UILabel` but ensure it is initialized before `viewDidAppear:` or else `school` object will be nil and you would be trying to set text on a nil object.

Comment: Check the label's frame to make sure it is not off screen (once you verify it isn't `nil`).

Comment: Please be advised, you are calling the `[super viewDidAppear:]` in a wrong manner, you shouldn't pas YES but you should pass the appropriate value which is the `animated` parameter itself. Like this: `[super viewDidAppear:animated]`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have **IBOutlet connected** for this UILabel. Check UILabel is initiated or not.
Try to NSLog the `school`.

Comment: As I said, IBOutlet is connected.

Comment: try to print UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `NSLog` is not returning a valid result it means that the value you're setting `schoolString` to is invalid (probably nil). It's likely an issue with your `PFUser` object instead. Make sure `user[KEY_SCHOOL]` is returning the result you want.

Perhaps you need to use `[user objectForKey:KEY_SCHOOL]` instead.